# Toast cancel not working, toast are still waiting in queue

Tags: android, kotlin

I found many similar question but none worked for me.

```
    fun check(isLeft:Boolean){
        val toast:Toast=Toast.makeText(this,"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        if(isLeft){
            if(left.text.toString().toInt()>right.text.toString().toInt()){
                main.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
                toast.cancel()
                toast.setText("Correct")
                toast.show()
            }else{
                main.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
                toast.cancel()
                toast.setText("In-Correct")
                toast.show()
            }
        }else{
            if(right.text.toString().toInt()>left.text.toString().toInt()){
                main.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
                toast.cancel()
                toast.setText("Correct")
                toast.show()
            }else{
                main.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
                toast.cancel()
                toast.setText("In-Correct")
                toast.show()
            }
        }
        randomNumber(left,right)
    }
```

Toast is waiting in queue rather then being displayed intently.Even when toast.cancel() is used by me.

Is toast.cancel() depreciated?

Clarification:-
I am not calling check once it is repeated task depending on the button pushed by the user.

Outcome:-
Toast with setText(correct)
or
Toast with setText(in-correct)

Comment: you are using .show() after .cancel(), so the Toast is going to be canceled then showed, delete any show after cancel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad,
I made toast a local object.
After check returns, there is no way to cancel() toast, as cancel() function needs the instance of toast which called the show() function.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Solution:-

Return toast object.

```
    fun check(isLeft:Boolean,toast:Toast):Toast {
    if(isLeft){
        if(left.text.toString().toInt()>right.text.toString().toInt()){
            main.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
            toast.cancel()
            toast.setText("Correct")
            toast.show()
        }else{
            main.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
            toast.cancel()
            toast.setText("In-Correct")
            toast.show()
        }
    }else{
        if(right.text.toString().toInt()>left.text.toString().toInt()){
            main.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
            toast.cancel()
            toast.setText("Correct")
            toast.show()
        }else{
            main.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
            toast.cancel()
            toast.setText("In-Correct")
            toast.show()
        }
    }
    randomNumber(left,right)
    toast.setText("")
    return toast
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

[toast.cancel()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast#cancel()) is not deprecated and
will cancel the toast-object that you created with makeText(). If you want to cancel a previously queued toast (by calling `.show()`) you must call `.cancel()` on that other instance. i.e.:

```
val toast1:Toast = Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"One",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
toast1.show()
toast1.cancel()
val toast2:Toast = Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Two",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
toast2.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

As the answer has said, the `cancel()` is for an instance created by `makeText()`. I can understand why do you want to call `cancel()` first. I think you want something like this:

```kotlin
toast?.apply { toast.cancel() }
toast=Toast.makeText(this,"Correct",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
toast.show()
```

And of course, you need to modify the other `setText()`s as well.